# Problems with a method imported from a SDK library

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to C# and ASP.NET and I have a problem with a library that I am importing. I have a small application that is going to convert a sound file in a format that is proprietaty to the vendor and they have an SDK that provides a method to make the conversion from their extension to .WAV format.

The issue I have is after importing the SDK library into VS2008, and putting the using statement on my code behind, I am getting an error when I try to use the method I need in order to make the conversion. My code is below and the error says:

> Name space ALTIHELPERLib
>
> Error 'ALTIHELPERLib.IAHelper.ADPCM2Wav(wavFilePath, filePath)'. Not all code paths return a value return

I have tried to look around for a solution but so far nothing has worked. Any help will be appreciate it. Here is my code:

```
string wavFilePath = @"\mylocation\"; //destination of file once onverted
string filePath = "\source\"; //location of source file

public string ALTIHELPERLib.IAHelper.ADPCM2Wav(wavFilePath, filePath){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your "public string ALTIHELPER..." method must return a string value since this is its signature. The body of your method is empty - { } so this is why you are getting this compilation error.

Comment: hello Everyone, and thank you Lubomir for your help, I found the issue and it was that the method is void so when I put void as the type the error goes away, however a new one comes up.

Comment: publicvoid ALTIHELPERLib.IAHelper.ADPCM2Wav(wavFilePath,filePath) right by the comma and the closing parenthesis I get this error stating "identifier expected" and I am not sure what that means. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you need to learn some basic C# syntax :)

The format of a function declaration in C# is like this

public void FunctionName(Type1 param1, Type2 param2)

where Type1 and Type2 are type names, like "string", "int", "TextBox", etc. and param1 and param2 are their names.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you've mixed up definitions and calls, instead try:

```
string wavFilePath = @"mylocation"; //destination of file once onverted
string filePath = @"source";        //location of source file

// notice: this is a method CALL not a DECLARATION
ALTIHELPERLib.IAHelper.ADPCM2Wav(wavFilePath, filePath);
```

Comment: @richcfml: you're welcome! You can click the check mark next to my answer to alert future visitors that this answer solved your problem.